# Running unittests with Isar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-isar

What is the right way to run unittests in [Isar](https://isar.dev/)? I keep getting `null` for `Isar.getInstance()!` preventing me from running any queries. Is the syntax different when running tests as opposed to running in the app? The docs has absolutely nothing on unittesting.

```dart
void main() async {
  setUpAll(() async {

    // This is always null
    Isar isar = Isar.getInstance()!;
    print(isar);   // null

  });
  test('', () {
    // Empty
  }, tags: 'service');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution on isar's GitHub issue [page](https://github.com/isar/isar/issues/1147).

```
void main() {
  late Isar isar;

  final data = [.. users data];

  setUpAll(() async {
    await Isar.initializeIsarCore(download: true);
    isar = await Isar.open([IsarUserSchema]);
    await isar.writeTxn(() async {
      await isar.users.clear();
    });
  });

  tearDownAll(() async {
    await isar.close();
  });

  setUp(() async {
    await isar.writeTxn(() async {
      await isar.users.clear();
    });
  });

  // Test for example
  test('addUsers add N users to DB', () async {
    await isar.writeTxn(() => isar.users.putAll(data));
    final result = await isar.users.count();
    expect(result, data.length);
  });
}
```

Comment: it is not work because when u want open Isar I mean use Isar.open you need a directory for do it and it is imposible in the setupall.

Comment: @RezaTaghizadeh you could specify a directory. The issue might be in your service/provider when you instantiate Isar for app. What error is showing?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to wrap the Isar with a singleton class using generics like this

```
abstract interface class IsarAdapter {
  Future<T?> get<T>(Id id);

  Future<void> save<T>(T item);
}

class IsarAdapterImpl implements IsarAdapter {
  IsarAdapterImpl._privateConstructor();

  static final IsarAdapterImpl _instance = IsarAdapterImpl._privateConstructor();

  static IsarAdapterImpl get instance => _instance;

  late final Isar isarInstance;

  Future<void> init() async {
    isarInstance = await Isar.open(
      [MonthlySummaryIsarSchema],
      directory: await Configuration.defaultDirectory,
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> save<T>(T item) async {
    await isarInstance.collection<T>().put(item);
  }

  @override
  Future<T?> get<T>(Id id) async {
    return await isarInstance.collection<T>().get(id);
  }
}
```

Then you can test like this:

```
 class MockIsarAdapter extends Mock implements IsarAdapter {}

class FakeMonthlySummaryIsar extends Fake implements MonthlySummaryIsar {}

void main() {
  late MockIsarAdapter mockIsarAdapter;
  late MonthlySummaryLocalDataSource dataSource;

  setUp(() {
    mockIsarAdapter = MockIsarAdapter();
    dataSource = MonthlySummaryIsarLocalDataSourceImpl(isarAdapter: mockIsarAdapter);

    registerFallbackValue(FakeMonthlySummaryIsar);
  });

  const tUserId = 'userId';

  final tMonthlySummary = MonthlySummary(
    yearMonth: DateTime(2022, 11),
    totalExpensesInCents: 200000,
    totalIncomeInCents: 345000,
  );

  final tMonthlySummaryIsar = MonthlySummaryIsar()
    ..id = '${tUserId}_${tMonthlySummary.yearMonth.month}_${tMonthlySummary.yearMonth.year}'
    ..yearMonth = tMonthlySummary.yearMonth
    ..totalExpensesInCents = tMonthlySummary.totalExpensesInCents
    ..totalIncomeInCents = tMonthlySummary.totalIncomeInCents;

  test('should return MonthlySummary when isarAdapter.get returns a non null MonthlySummaryIsar',
      () async {
    //arrange
    when(() => mockIsarAdapter.get<MonthlySummaryIsar>(any()))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => tMonthlySummaryIsar);

    //act
    final result = await dataSource.getMonthlySummary(
      userId: tUserId,
      month: tMonthlySummary.yearMonth.month,
      year: tMonthlySummary.yearMonth.year,
    );

    //assert
    expect(result, tMonthlySummary);

    verify(() => mockIsarAdapter.get<MonthlySummaryIsar>(tMonthlySummaryIsar.id))).called(1);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockIsarAdapter);
  });
}
```